# Can't run java applet code on cmd

Tags: java, applet

I can't seem to run my java applet code in `cmd(directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin).`

The error says

```
rectangle.java:12: error while writing rectangle: rectangle.class <Access is denied> public class rectangle extends Applet
```

My code:

```
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;

    /*
    <applet code="rectangle" height=500 width=700>
    </applet>
    */

    public class rectangle extends Applet
    {


    int apw1[];
    int p[];
    int i=0,n,n1;
    Graphics g= getGraphics();

    public void init()
    {
    try
    {



    BufferedReader obj=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    System.out.println("ENTER no. of processes:");
     n=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());

    int ch;
    int bt[]=new int[n];


    do{

        System.out.println("MENU FOR CPU SCHEDULING");
        System.out.println("1.FCFS method");
        System.out.println("2.SHORTEST JOB FIRST method(non-preemptive)");
        System.out.println("3.SHORTEST JOB FIRST method(preemptive)");
        System.out.println("4.ROUND ROBIN method");
        System.out.println("5.PRIORITY method (non-preemptive)");
        System.out.println("6.PRIORITY method (preemptive)");
        System.out.println("7.EXIT");
        System.out.println("ENTER YOUR CHOICE");

            ch=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:

                {

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {System.out.println("ENTER burst time for each process: p"+(i+1));
                bt[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }
                n1=n;
                int turn[]=new int[n];
                apw1=new int[n+1];
                apw1[0]=0;
                float t=0;
                float tu=0;
                p=new int[n];
                for( i=1;i<=n;i++)
                apw1[i]=bt[i-1]+apw1[i-1];
                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("indivisual waiting time for process p"+(i+1)+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");
                }

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                p[i]=i+1;
                System.out.print(p[i]);
                        }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                t+=apw1[i];

                float avg=t/n;
                System.out.println("average waiting time is:"+avg);

                /*for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                System.out.println("response time for process p"+(i+1)+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");*/

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                turn[i]=bt[i]+apw1[i];
                System.out.println("turnaround time for process p"+(i+1)+"is"+turn[i]+" ");
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                tu+=turn[i];

                float avg1=tu/n;
                System.out.println("average turn-around time is:"+avg1);


                paint(g);
                }



                break;

            case 2:
                {
                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {System.out.println("ENTER burst time for each process: p"+(i+1));
                bt[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }
                n1=n;
                int temp;
                float t=0;
                int turn[]=new int[n];
                apw1=new int[n+1];
                apw1[0]=0;
                p=new int[n];
                int sj[]=new int[n];
                float tu=0;

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                sj[i]=bt[i];

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                if(sj[i]>sj[j])
                {
                temp=sj[i];
                sj[i]=sj[j];
                sj[j]=temp;
                }



                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                if(sj[i]==bt[j])
                p[i]=j+1;

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                apw1[i+1]=sj[i]+apw1[i];

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("indivisual waiting time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                 t+=apw1[i];
                float avg=t/n;
                System.out.println("average waiting time is:"+avg);

                /*for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                System.out.println("response time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");*/

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                int k=p[i];
                turn[i]=bt[k-1]+apw1[i];
                System.out.println("turnaround time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+turn[i]+" ");
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                tu+=turn[i];

                float avg1=tu/n;
                System.out.println("average turn-around time is:"+avg1);


                paint(g);

                }


                break;

        case 3:
                    {

                    int total=0,k=0,co=0,small=999,sp=0,sp1=0,x=0,count=0;
                    int pro[][]=new int[n][3];
                    int wt[]=new int[n];
                    int wt1[]=new int[n];
                    int bt1[]=new int[n];
                    int tt[]=new int[n];
                    apw1=new int [20];
                    p=new int[20];

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                    pro[i][0]=i;
                    System.out.print("Burst Time for P"+i+" :");
                    pro[i][1]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                    total+=pro[i][1];
                    System.out.print("Arrival Time for P"+i+" :");
                    pro[i][2]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    wt1[i]=pro[i][2];

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    bt1[i]=pro[i][1];

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                        if(pro[i][2]>pro[j][2])
                        {
                            int temp[]=pro[i];
                            pro[i]=pro[j];
                            pro[j]=temp;
                        }

                    for(int i=1;i<=total;i++)
                    {
                    small=999;
                    for(int j=co;j<n;j++)
                        if(k>=pro[j][2])
                        co++;
                    for(int j=0;j<co;j++)
                    {
                        if(small>pro[j][1]&&pro[j][1]!=0)
                        {
                            small=pro[j][1];
                            sp=pro[j][0];
                            sp1=j;
                        }
                    }
                    if(p[x]==sp)
                    {
                    apw1[x+1]++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    x++;
                    p[x]=sp;
                    apw1[x+1]=apw1[x];
                    apw1[x+1]++;
                    count++;
                    }



                    pro[sp1][1]-=1;
                    if(pro[sp1][1]==0)
                    tt[sp1]=i;
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        if(pro[j][1]!=0&&j!=sp)
                            wt[j]+=1;
                    }
                    k++;
                    }
                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                        if(pro[i][0]>pro[j][0])
                        {
                            int temp[]=pro[i];
                            pro[i]=pro[j];
                            pro[j]=temp;
                            int tem=wt[i],tem1=tt[i];
                            wt[i]=wt[j];
                            wt[j]=tem;
                            tt[i]=tt[j];
                            tt[j]=tem1;

                        }

                    System.out.println();

                    for(int m=0;m<=count;m++)
                    p[m]+=1;


                    double awt=0.0,att=0.0;

                    System.out.println();
                    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                    {
                    System.out.println("waiting time for process p "+i+"  "+(wt[i]-wt1[i]));
                    awt+=(wt[i]-wt1[i]);
                    att+=(wt[i]-wt1[i]+bt1[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                    {
                    System.out.println("turnaround time for process p"+i+"  "+(wt[i]-wt1[i]+bt1[i]));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Average waiting time : "+(awt/n));
                    System.out.println("Average turnaround time : "+(att/n));
                    n1=count+1;
                    paint(g);

                    }
                break;

            case 4:
                        {
                        for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                        {System.out.println("ENTER burst time for each process: p"+(i+1));
                        bt[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                        }
                        int ro[]=new int[n];
                        apw1=new int[20];
                                apw1[0]=0;

                        int sq[]=new int[20];

                        int temp;
                        float t=0;
                        float tu=0;
                        int apw[]=new int[n];
                        int bttime=0;
                        int turn[]=new int[n];
                        int f=0;

                        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                        {
                        ro[i]=bt[i];

                        }


                        p=new int[30];
                        System.out.println("enter time quantum");
                        int ts=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                        int k=0;
                        sq[k]=0;
                        i=0;
                        temp=ts;

                        int count=0;

                        do
                        {

                        if(ro[i]==0)
                            {
                        i++;
                        sq[k]=sq[k-1]+temp;
                        }

                        else
                            if(ro[i]>=ts)
                        {
                        ro[i]=ro[i]-ts;
                        p[k]=i+1;
                        k++;
                        i++;
                        temp=ts;
                        sq[k]=sq[k-1]+temp;
                        turn[i-1]=sq[k];

                            f=0;
                        for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
                        f+=ro[m];

                        count++;
                        }

                            else
                        if(ro[i]>0 && ro[i]<ts)
                        {
                        temp=ro[i];
                        ro[i]=0;
                        p[k]=i+1;
                        i++;
                        k++;
                        sq[k]=sq[k-1]+temp;
                        turn[i-1]=sq[k];

                        f=0;
                        for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
                        f+=ro[m];

                        count++;

                        }

                        if(i==n)
                        i=0;


                        }while(f!=0);


                        System.out.println();

                        for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
                        {
                        apw1[i]=sq[i];
                        }

                        System.out.println();


                        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                        {
                            apw[i]=turn[i]-bt[i];
                            t+=apw[i];
                            tu+=turn[i];
                        }

                        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                        System.out.println(" waiting time for p"+(i+1)+"is:"+apw[i]);

                        float avg=t/n;
                        System.out.println("average waiting time is:"+avg);


                        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                        System.out.println("turn around time is:"+turn[i]);



                        float avg1=tu/n;
                        System.out.println("average turn-around time is:"+avg1);


                        n1=count;



                        paint(g);



                        }
                break;


            case 5:
                {
                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {System.out.println("ENTER burst time for each process: p"+(i+1));
                bt[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }
                n1=n;
                int pr[]=new int[n];
                int pr1[]=new int[n];
                float t=0;
                int temp;
                int turn[]=new int[n];
                p=new int[n];
                apw1=new int[n+1];
                apw1[0]=0;
                float tu=0;


                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("Enter the priority for p"+(i+1));
                pr[i]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                }

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                pr1[i]=pr[i];
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                if(pr1[i]>pr1[j])
                {
                temp=pr1[i];
                pr1[i]=pr1[j];
                pr1[j]=temp;
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                if(pr1[i]==pr[j])
                p[i]=j+1;

                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                int k=p[i];
                apw1[i+1]=bt[k-1]+apw1[i];
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("indivisual waiting time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                t+=apw1[i];
                float avg=t/n;
                System.out.println("average waiting time is:"+avg);

                /*for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                System.out.println("response time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+apw1[i]+" ");*/


                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                int k=p[i];
                turn[i]=bt[k-1]+apw1[i];
                System.out.println("turnaround time for process p"+p[i]+"is"+turn[i]+" ");
                }

                for( i=0;i<n;i++)
                tu+=turn[i];

                float avg1=tu/n;
                System.out.println("average turn-around time is:"+avg1);


                paint(g);

                }

                break;


            case 6:

                {
                int total=0,k=0,co=0,small=999,sp=0,sp1=0,x=0,count=0;
                int pro[][]=new int[n][4];
                int wt[]=new int[n];
                int wt1[]=new int[n];
                int bt1[]=new int[n];
                int tt[]=new int[n];
                apw1=new int [20];
                p=new int[20];

                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                pro[i][0]=i;
                System.out.print("Burst Time for P"+i+" :");
                pro[i][3]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                total+=pro[i][3];
                System.out.print("Arrival Time for P"+i+" :");
                pro[i][2]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                System.out.print("Priority for P"+i+" :");
                pro[i][1]=Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());

                }
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                wt1[i]=pro[i][2];

                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                bt1[i]=pro[i][3];

                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                    if(pro[i][2]>pro[j][2])
                    {
                        int temp[]=pro[i];
                        pro[i]=pro[j];
                        pro[j]=temp;
                    }

                for(int i=1;i<=total;i++)
                {
                small=999;
                for(int j=co;j<n;j++)
                    if(k>=pro[j][2])
                    co++;
                for(int j=0;j<co;j++)
                {
                    if(small>pro[j][1]&&pro[j][3]!=0)
                    {
                        small=pro[j][1];
                        sp=pro[j][0];
                        sp1=j;
                    }
                }
                if(p[x]==sp)
                {
                apw1[x+1]++;

                }
                else
                {
                x++;
                p[x]=sp;
                apw1[x+1]=apw1[x];
                apw1[x+1]++;
                count++;
                }



                pro[sp1][3]-=1;
                if(pro[sp1][3]==0)
                tt[sp1]=i;
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if(pro[j][3]!=0&&j!=sp)
                        wt[j]+=1;
                }
                k++;
                }
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                    if(pro[i][0]>pro[j][0])
                    {
                        int temp[]=pro[i];
                        pro[i]=pro[j];
                        pro[j]=temp;
                        int tem=wt[i],tem1=tt[i];
                        wt[i]=wt[j];
                        wt[j]=tem;
                        tt[i]=tt[j];
                        tt[j]=tem1;

                    }

                System.out.println();

                for(int m=0;m<=count;m++)
                p[m]+=1;


                double awt=0.0,att=0.0;

                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                {
                System.out.println("waiting time for process p "+i+"  "+(wt[i]-wt1[i]));
                awt+=(wt[i]-wt1[i]);
                att+=(wt[i]-wt1[i]+bt1[i]);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                {
                System.out.println("turnaround time for process p"+i+"  "+(wt[i]-wt1[i]+bt1[i]));
                }
                System.out.println("Average waiting time : "+(awt/n));
                System.out.println("Average turnaround time : "+(att/n));
                n1=count+1;
                paint(g);

                }



        }

       } while(ch!=7);




    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {}

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {




    for(int j=1;j<=n1;j++)
    {

    g.drawRect(50,50,(apw1[j]*20),30);
    g.drawString("p"+p[j-1],(55+(apw1[j-1]*20)),70);
    g.drawString(""+apw1[j-1],50+(apw1[j-1]*20),100);
    }
    g.drawString(""+apw1[n1],50+(apw1[n1]*20),100);




    }

    }
```

Comment: applets shouldn't be run by command prompt, but in a browser, that's their main function.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: However to check them you can run them using command like appletviewer here is some more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html

Comment: I tried running it in a browser. The error says "UnsupportedClassVersionError. rectangle: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" how should I fix this?

Comment: full stacktrace

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.windowsSettingChange(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Check your JRE/JDK version and compare whether you've compiled your code in same version as you are trying to run with it.